# Flutter late initialization exception when logging out from page that has google map

Tags: flutter

I am having this weird error. I am using Get. I have a controller `map_controller.dart`, I have following code along with other codes

```
final Completer<GoogleMapController> mapController = Completer();
late final GoogleMapController gmcontroller;
```

and i have disposed the controller correctly like this.

```
@override
  void onInit() async {
    super.onInit();
    gmcontroller = await mapController.future;
  }

@override
  void onClose() async {
    gmcontroller.dispose();
    super.onClose();
  }
```

In page we display Google map with a marker of the user position. This page also has a  button that logs out user
This button executes following code when tapped.

```
  Get.offAll(() => const LoginPage());
```

**Problem:**

When I clicked the button I get exception -

> LateError (LateInitializationError: Field 'gmcontroller' has not
> been initialized.)

If I use `Get.off` instead of `Get.offAll`, the issue doesn't occur.

How do I get rid of the exception?

Thanks

Comment: Where do you create and assign`GoogleMapController gmcontroller` ?

Comment: what about making `gmcontroller` to nullable from `late` .

Answer (score 0):

please, try this:

```
class _MapWidgetState extends State<MapWidget> {
  final Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();
  
  ....
  
  }
```

then when building map:

```
  GoogleMap(
    ...
    onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
      _controller.complete(controller);

    },
    ...
)
```

not sure if the controller should be disposed